# Android : Exit application

Tags: android

I went throgh different questions realted to this topic and still have few doubts.

Que One: In my application i have multiple activities A->B->C

A->B2->C2..
A-B3-C3...

is the flow . I have "back" and "home" button for each activity to go to previous activity and A respectively.

Initially i was launching each of these as "single task" and everything appeared to be good.

Now i wanted to handle error condition and thus the exit application came to picture.
SO from my reading i understand its not "good" to launch each activity as single task 
( i ma not very clear the reason or am i wrong here )
SO i changed all activities launch mode as standard
So one thing i noticed is switching between actvities throu "back" or "home" is slow than earlier. SO iam i doing the right thing here

Que two:now i have my code

```
    if (some error)
    {
        this.finish()       
    }

    code line;
```

this is in my root activity A and will be hit before launching any other activity
But what i see is finish is executed but before application really exit , code line is executed leading to some exception. My expected behaviour is once i call finish , it is like a return from this activity and no more code executed here

Que 3: Now when we call a finish on the root activity, who will actually handle it.

Comment: you can use:   intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); before calling home activity.

Comment: how can i set intent flag for home activity . Is there a way to specify it in androidmanifest .
Also each time i press"home" fron any of my activities all in the stack will be removed ?

Comment: from othe activity youru can use:

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
    intent.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    context.startActivity (intent);

Comment: Better you use `try{} catch{}`

Comment: Are you making any service call or Async task before you call finish() ?

Comment: No.I am trying to open a URL and if any network error i want to exit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ListActivity.this.startActivity(i); 
finish();
```

Comment: exit your app...code copy to paste in the Onclick ...try this...Hope this helps!

Comment: @Android I think he's asking you to explain what that code does and how it works.
preetha, I haven't read through your code, but have you looked up those Intent methods in the API?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)

Comment: finish your current Activity and exit your app.

Answer (score 0):

Close all the previous activities as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

Then in MainActivity onCreate() method add this to finish the MainActivity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
        finish();
        return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
    }
```